# Why do I need to initialize a variable to use "toUpperCase" method?

Tags: java

This only works when I initialize the variable `String convert;` with the use of the method `toUpperCase();`

```
public class Conversion {
   String convert;

   public String convertString(String t){
       convert = t;
       convert = convert.toUpperCase();  //MY QUESTION RELATES TO THIS LINE
       return convert;
   }
}
```

When I just set code:

```
convert.toUpperCase();
return convert;
```

it does not work. Why? Why do I have to initialize `convert` first?

Comment: Because you cannot call methods on null objects. What would you expect the result of this to be? `null.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Why wouldn't you have to? What should .toUpperCase() on a a null object do instead?

Comment: The String#toUpperCase returns the resulting String, it doesn't modify the current string to an uppercase one. So you have to capture it with as assignation: `convert = ...;`. But you can call it on `t`, instead of assigning and calling it with a second assignation.

Comment: but for example if the user input is "hello". Because of convert = t; how can convert be null? convert should be "hello" now shouldnt it?

Comment: Because user input is contained inside `t`, not `convert`. Convert would still be null no matter what the user entered (and by this I assume you mean passed as a parameter to the method because you don't show any sort of user input code). Setting `convert = t` ensures that convert is not null which is why the code works. Without that line convert will be null.

Comment: im sorry but i really dont get it. the input is passed to the method by parameter convertString(String t). String t for example is "hello". now in the next line I set convert = t. So convert is "hello" now isn't it? Now why cant i just use convert.toUppercase() but need to set conver = convert.toUppercase();

Comment: `toUppercase` obviously doesn't change the object where it is called on, since Strings are immutable. It returns a completely new String with the applied changes.

Comment: I'm confused as to what your confusion is. If you have this line of code `convert = t` then we know convert is not null and so now you can call `convert.toUpperCase()` and the code works fine. If you do not have this line of code `convert = t` you cannot call `convert.toUpperCase()` because `convert` may be null. If you expect calling `convert.toUpperCase()` to do anything, it won't. It does not modify what you give it - it makes a copy of the input, modifies the copy, then sends the copy back to you. To see that result you have to assign the result to something.

Comment: thank you sir, now i got it. i expected the method to do something, but know i understand that it only makes a copy and modifies it!

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let us know the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be writing

```
convert = t.toUpperCase();
```

as the `convert` variable may not be initialized. After all, you're supposed to initialize it with the `t` parameter. Without it you'd get a `NullPointerException`, and the compiler can deduce this and just refuses to compile the code.

But the whole `convert` variable is dubious. You could just as well write the method as `return t.toUpperCase()`, but that would make your whole class useless, unless your intention is to keep track of the last string you've converted.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a String, its default value is null. That's the same behavior of all the references types.

You can't use functions like toUpperString() in a null value.

```
convert = t; //Here, convert is not null anymore
convert = convert.toUpperCase();
```

However, your function is very simple, if you don't do anything with convert, aside call toUpperString(), is better change the return to

```
return t.toUpperString
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize "convert" because in your method there isn't a local variable called convert. Your method is useless because witt 1 row you can convert every String you want..

However your code:

```
        public class YourClass {
           public static void main(String[] args){
              String convert = "Which string you prefere";
              convert.toUpperCase(); // You just finished
    }
}
```

Your code is wrong because the method uppercase already exists! You use only more memory with the program and it is useless! THIS metod below is WRONG.

```
    public class Conversion {
       String convert = "Your String here";
       convert = convertString(convert);

       public String convertString(String t){
// In any case if you want a variable convert in here(local), you have to declare it again.. But inside this method.
           t.toUpperCase();  // Your "t" is the string you passed over (convert)
           return t;
       }
```

Comment: How has this answer added anything that is not already in the posted answers?

Comment: I create the full program if he had some problems, what's the problem? If the answer is similar like others, he could convince.